# Continue on PHP

Tags: php

Hi there i have some questions, how to continuing the data while the condition has reach 500 value on the new file and then create some random number beside the sitemap name. this is my script:

```
$rand = rand(1,9);
$open1 = fopen("sitemap-$rand.txt", 'w');
$web = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
$ws = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$i = 1;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $hasil = home_base_url().strtolower($value).'.html'."\n";
    fwrite($open1, $hasil);
    if (++$i == 500) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You mean that there are 500 lines, per random numbered sitemap?

```
if (++$i == 500) {
    $value = rand(0,9);// set valuie to a new random value
    $i = 0; // reset the counter
}
```

*N.B.: It might be that the loop will pick the same random number twice. Either pick a larger number to decrease the odds, or create a small function which knows which names are used, so you must pick a new name.*

Comment: How can i break the loop and then continue the loop on the new file sir ?

Comment: You dont break it. When you are at 500, you change `$value`, so it'll write to a new file automatically

Comment: If this still is too complex, you should ask someone in real life to help you